# Book about a religious kid who starts to see mythical creatures in the real world

Tags: story-identification, books

I've been looking for this book I read in 2007-2008 when I was in high school.

Basically there's this religious kid who starts seeing mythical creatures in the real world. If memories serve me right this kid, a fairy, and a leprechaun have to race against time to get to a portal that's in an office building. The building is run and controlled by evil centaurs or minotaurs and there are demons destroying the world.

If I remember the book cover had just a solo red demon on it.

The book makes a direct reference Harry Potter by saying that he's from the type of family that's outside the movie theater protesting the new boy wizard movie.